# Bootstrap modal-dialog resize with Maximize/Minimize icons in Angular 7

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular7

I am using **Bootstrap Model-dialog** popup to display my content in my Angular 7 application. using this in multiple places, I am changing the width and height of popup against the content loaded.

Now I need to add the **Minimize/Maximize** icons to popup. Users can resize the popup by clicking on min/max icons. is there any property to resize popup width and height.

```
  this.showModelPopup.open().then((result) => {  
}, (reason) => {   
});
```

In Html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div id="Status" data-grid="col-md-12">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="close"  (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>

                <div>
                   // My content here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular html template is going to look like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="my-modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <form>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="fa fa-window-maximize cursor-pointer modal-resize" (click)="maximize();" *ngIf="!this.isMaximize" title="Maximize"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-window-restore cursor-pointer modal-resize" (click)="restore()" *ngIf="this.isMaximize" title="Restore"></span>
            Your header
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="my-modal-body">
            Your body
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Your footer
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And your respective angular component .ts class file going to have following:

```
isMaximize = false;

maximize() {
this.isMaximize = !this.isMaximize;
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.maxWidth = "100%";
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.margin = "auto";
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById('my-modal-body').style.maxHeight = "calc(100vh - 139px)";
}

restore() {
this.isMaximize = !this.isMaximize;
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.maxWidth = "";
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.margin = "";
document.getElementById('my-modal-dialog').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('my-modal-body').style.maxHeight = "calc(100vh - 190px)";
}
```